# Mongoose query inside a .then, receiving warnings and errors despite working

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am a little bit confused after reading around the documentation on whether or not I can do a mongoose query within a promise handle. In this case I am trying to loop over an array of objects in portfolio.coin and then look up their current prices in another model. Is there a better way to do this? The following code works, but I get Unhandledpromiserejection warnings and documentnotfound error.

```
// @route:       GET api/portfolio/
// @description: Get the latest portfolio with price changes
// @access:      Private
router.get('/', passport.authenticate('jwt',
  { session: false }), (req, res) => {
    Portfolio.findOne({
      user: req.user.id
    }).then(portfolio => {
      if (portfolio) {
        // Loop over all the coins in the portfolio
        portfolio.coin.forEach((item, index) => {

          // In scope object 
          let details = {
            _id: item._id,
            exchange: item.exchange,
            currencyname: item.currencyname,
            currencyquantity: item.currencyquantity,
            currencypaidwith: item.currencypaidwith,
            pricepaid: item.pricepaid,
            currentprice: 0,
            pricedifference: 0
          };

          // For each coin find the market prices
          Market.findOne({
            exchange: item.exchange,
            coin_one: item.currencyname,
            coin_two: item.currencypaidwith
          }).then(result => {
            if (result) {

              // details
              details.currentprice = result.price;
              details.pricedifference = result.price; // TODO: percentage 
              portfolio.coin[index] = details;

              if (portfolio.coin.length >= index) {
                portfolio.save().then(portfolio => res.json(portfolio)).catch(err => res.status(404).json({ nodoc: "somethin went wrong" }));
              }
            }
          }).catch(err => res.status(404).json({ nodoc: "could not find a doc" }))
        });
      }
    })
  })
```

Comment: you need to add `.catch` in last row

Comment: Could you kindly be more specific where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `.catch` in last row

```
// @route:       GET api/portfolio/
// @description: Get the latest portfolio with price changes
// @access:      Private
router.get('/', passport.authenticate('jwt',
{ session: false }), (req, res) => {
    Portfolio.findOne({
    user: req.user.id
    }).then(portfolio => {
    if (portfolio) {
        // Loop over all the coins in the portfolio
        portfolio.coin.forEach((item, index) => {

        // In scope object 
        let details = {
            _id: item._id,
            exchange: item.exchange,
            currencyname: item.currencyname,
            currencyquantity: item.currencyquantity,
            currencypaidwith: item.currencypaidwith,
            pricepaid: item.pricepaid,
            currentprice: 0,
            pricedifference: 0
        };

        // For each coin find the market prices
        Market.findOne({
            exchange: item.exchange,
            coin_one: item.currencyname,
            coin_two: item.currencypaidwith
        }).then(result => {
            if (result) {

            // details
            details.currentprice = result.price;
            details.pricedifference = result.price; // TODO: percentage 
            portfolio.coin[index] = details;

            if (portfolio.coin.length >= index) {
                portfolio.save().then(portfolio => res.json(portfolio)).catch(err => res.status(404).json({ nodoc: "somethin went wrong" }));
            }
            }
        }).catch(err => res.status(404).json({ nodoc: "could not find a doc" }))
        });
    }
    }).catch(err => res.status(404).json({ nodoc: "could not find a portfolio" }))
})
```

Comment: yes i added there just to confirm, i still continue to receive: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DocumentNotFoundError: No document found for query "{ _id: 5b1b1b1ffcde8bc049dea4b0, __v: 23 }". if my array has two objects, and they are both getting updated like normal, where is the last query coming from, this is strange.

Comment: I have updated answer, also need to add a catch for portfolio.save()

Comment: Hey thanks, i will accept as answer. i also needed to explicitly map the fields in the object on a one-to-one. rather than a total replace. i get a new error "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" but thats for another question, unless you know what may cause. thanks

Comment: fixed also with:               if (portfolio.coin.length - 1 === index) {
                portfolio.save().then(portfolio => res.json(portfolio)).catch(err => res.status(404).json({ nodoc: "somethin went wrong" }));
              }